# How can I convert CLAWS7 tags to Penn tags?

Tags: nlp, pos-tagger, part-of-speech

Does anyone of you know a way to convert a tag from CLAWS7 tagset to it's equivalent in Penn tagset?

CLAWS7 tagset: http://ucrel.lancs.ac.uk/claws7tags.html

Penn tagset: http://www.mozart-oz.org/mogul/doc/lager/brill-tagger/penn.html

Comment: I guess there aren't many people willing to manually match the tagsets. Do you still need the tag converter? if you want i can spend 1-2 hours writing a piece of code for it.

Comment: Did you ever find something?

Comment: @alvas If you know of or can publish a mapping (without necessarily any source code), I think many would find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mapping table a converter script over here: https://gist.github.com/nschneid/6476715